# c# QuadTree yielding properly

Tags: c#, performance, iterator

I have implemented a QuadTree of my own, and I'm afraid I didn't use yield properly when I query my tree, my fear is that I create O(HN) iterators.

Could you direct me how to better improve the performance of the following code?

QuadTree

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query(string leafId, Circle shape)
    {
        // Gets the relevant parent by a leafId Query (this is O(lg H))
        var startNode = GetParentIntersecting(leafId, shape);

        return startNode.Query(shape);
    }
```

QuadTreeNode

```
 public IEnumerable<T> Query(IShape shape)
    {
        var results = new HashSet<T>();

        foreach (var content in _contents)
        {
            if (shape.Contains(content.GetPosition()))
            {
                //Debug.Log(content.GetPosition());
                yield return content;
                //results.Add(content);
            }
        }

        if (IsLeaf)
            yield break;

        foreach (var node in Nodes)
        {
            if (node.IsEmpty && node.IsLeaf)
                continue;

            foreach (var result in node.Query(shape))
            {
                results.Add(result);
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide all the relevant code. Also some tests would be useful. If I cannot copy your code and compile it without adding anything extra I vote to close for lack of concrete context.

Comment: Please provide the full class, otherwise we can't really suggest performance improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use yield properly, it's OK to yield from inside nested loops. But all the code behind your first foreach is kind of useless, it's not doing anything useful.

First the `yield break` is useless, cause there are no more yields following, there are no more return values produced no matter if IsLeaf true or false. Iteration ends anyway.

Second you fill up `results` with something, but the content of results is lost, then the Method exits.